# Android TaskStackBuilder addNextIntentWithParentStack freezes app

Tags: android, android-intent, freeze, taskstackbuilder

I am trying to show a notification from a BroadcastReceiver in my app, but creating the parent stack is giving me problems. The app just freezes (no exception, just freezes) when I call the following code

```
Intent notifIntent = new Intent(context, NotificacionesActivity.class);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(notifIntent); // <- code execution freezes here
PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Which basically is a copy-paste from the android docs here: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation#build_a_pendingintent_with_a_back_stack

After a few seconds the output shows this

```
Thread[3,tid=5321,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xf005cc00,peer=0x16940088,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
Wrote stack traces to '[tombstoned]'
```

and then starts spamming

```
Background concurrent copying GC freed 87185(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 16% free, 30MB/36MB, paused 223us total 101.944ms
```

I've looked it up and seems that a tomstone trace should be saved somewhere in /data, but I cant find anything there, I think the log never gets saved.
The activity has the parentActivityName declared in the manifest.

```
<activity
   android:name=".activity.NotificacionesActivity"
   android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainActivity"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
   />
```

The notification shows up if I dont create the pending intent so I'm pretty sure that the code above is the one causing trouble.
I've tried on Api 28 and 29 (android 9 & 10), uninstalling the app, and even creating a new virtual device, the result is the same, funny thing is that this code was once working, and now it just doesnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**
It seems my mainActivity had itself as parentActivityName, so creating a stack was causing a recursive loop lol.